# What format is this CSV written in?

Tags: qgis, csv, well-known-text

I would like to work with this set of data and transfrom it into an shapefile, but I have no clue which language it is written in, nor how to convert it. Any hints?:

```
id,geo_point_2d,geo_shape,muerdago,p_sp_her_d,zonifica,subcat_sed,subcve_sed,p_manejo,tipo,p_sp_abs_d,f_decreto,direccion,gid,cve_delg,p_arbustiv,ubicacion,nombre,delegacion,p_sp_arb_d,p_herbaceo,p_sp_do_mu,p_arboreo,categoria,superficie,e_urbano,perimetro,cve_sedema,responsabl
0,"19.4877568178,-99.2060645931","{""type"": ""MultiPolygon"", ""coordinates"": [[[[-99.2063901369562, 19.488192302215793], [-99.20556202053083, 19.487955527548596], [-99.20572621602916, 19.487317782714538], [-99.20633421530209, 19.487497445904744], [-99.20658050854802, 19.48756645560521], [-99.20646632656124, 19.48794381572397], [-99.2063901369562, 19.488192302215793]]]]}",Ausencia,,,Panteones,604.0,,,,,Román Álvarez Moreno,268,2,,,,Azcapotzalco,,,,,Equipamientos urbanos con vegetación,6660.02755418,,329.26473795,600,
1,"19.3887689803,-99.116393168","{""type"": ""MultiPolygon"", ""coordinates"": [[[[-99.11678804338746, 19.389035577395834], [-99.11637228211686, 19.388873052535505], [-99.11608502887533, 19.388823917112617], [-99.11590738542336, 19.388823917112617], [-99.11582801281715, 19.388816357816783], [-99.11585069070463, 19.38872942591474], [-99.11585447035255, 19.388650053308538], [-99.11585447035255, 19.388627375421056], [-99.11607746957951, 19.388623595773133], [-99.11682961951452, 19.388642494012707], [-99.11678804338746, 19.389035577395834]]]]}",Ausencia,,,Deportivos,601.0,,,,,Avenida Canal deTezontle,87,8,,,,Iztacalco,,,,,Equipamientos urbanos con vegetación,2917.25783681,,272.243614174,600,
2,"19.3928871121,-99.0869912505","{""type"": ""MultiPolygon"", ""coordinates"": [[[[-99.08651023736049, 19.393671394490635], [-99.08648236539211, 19.393674181687473], [-99.0864656422111, 19.393657458506446], [-99.0864656422111, 19.393643522522268], [-99.08750247943445, 19.392063181915717], [-99.08751920261547, 19.392063181915713], [-99.08753871299332, 19.39206875630939], [-99.08754150019016, 19.39208826668725], [-99.08752756420597, 19.39210777706511], [-99.08651023736049, 19.393671394490635]]]]}",Ausencia,,,Camellones centrales y laterales,203.0,,,,,Canal Río Churubusco,180,8,,,CAMELLON EJE 4 OTE. (RIO CHURUBUSCO),Iztacalco,,,,,Áreas verdes complementarias o ligadas a la red vial,1086.30564576,,425.043655518,200,
3,"19.383106069,-99.1073609486","{""type"": ""MultiPolygon"", ""coordinates"": [[[[-99.10779818021125, 19.383334000238698], [-99.10688047454205, 19.38320978041055], [-99.10693371161126, 19.382867542108496], [-99.10785395237899, 19.383017112921983], [-99.10779818021125, 19.383334000238698]]]]}",Ausencia,,,Unidades habitacionales,602.0,,,,,CORTEZA,89,8,,AV. GIRASOL ENTRE MAGUEY Y CUMBRE.,"PARQUE GIRASOL ""CENTRAL INFONAVIT"".",Iztacalco,,,,,Equipamientos urbanos con vegetación,3605.70404646,,269.209436459,600,
4,"19.3822134465,-99.1028423436","{""type"": ""MultiPolygon"", ""coordinates"": [[[[-99.10389120954979, 19.383145456493573], [-99.10354902937245, 19.383098544695063], [-99.10326479906385, 19.3827646430704], [-99.1032068491951, 19.382742566929927], [-99.10319581112486, 19.382706693201655], [-99.10304679717667, 19.38269289561386], [-99.10298608779037, 19.382668059955822], [-99.10297780923769, 19.382745326447488], [-99.10283707384217, 19.382717731271896], [-99.10284535239485, 19.38265978140315], [-99.10278464300855, 19.382618388639763], [-99.10276256686808, 19.38254940070077], [-99.10270185748178, 19.38244453903353], [-99.10250041269995, 19.38240314627014], [-99.10249489366483, 19.382353474954076], [-99.10243142476097, 19.38235071543652], [-99.10242038669074, 19.382392108199905], [-99.10227965129522, 19.382356234471636], [-99.10227965129522, 19.382334158331155], [-99.10210028265386, 19.382309322673127], [-99.10205888989047, 19.382331398813598], [-99.10191263545985, 19.382370032059434], [-99.10180501427503, 19.382422462893057], [-99.10185744510866, 19.3820002567065], [-99.10189607835449, 19.38198369960114], [-99.10195954725836, 19.381696709774975], [-99.10191815449495, 19.3816884312223], [-99.10196506629347, 19.38131313683426], [-99.10203405423245, 19.381332453457176], [-99.1020506113378, 19.381277263105982], [-99.10251421028775, 19.38135452959765], [-99.10260251484966, 19.38157253148482], [-99.10250869125265, 19.381608405213093], [-99.10258871726185, 19.38179881192468], [-99.10267978134131, 19.381773976266647], [-99.10270737651689, 19.381887116486574], [-99.10314889932636, 19.382055447057684], [-99.10354902937245, 19.382132713549336], [-99.1038442977513, 19.38216582776006], [-99.10385809533909, 19.382430741445734], [-99.10377255029475, 19.38256595780614], [-99.10380566450547, 19.382695655131418], [-99.103877411962, 19.3828253524567], [-99.10390500713758, 19.382968847369774], [-99.10389120954979, 19.383145456493573]]]]}",Ausencia,,,Unidades habitacionales,602.0,,,,,El Lago,90,8,,,,Iztacalco,,,,,Equipamientos urbanos con vegetación,19619.3615774,,798.409226667,600,
5,"19.3556704267,-99.1284539832","{""type"": ""MultiPolygon"", ""coordinates"": [[[[-99.12837265656651, 19.355780376021457], [-99.12804180704703, 19.355766921301715], [-99.12805606780219, 19.355551645634975], [-99.12840403022784, 19.35555837300387], [-99.12842969958712, 19.355524736156674], [-99.12854025526477, 19.35552875674728], [-99.12853615162528, 19.355564321298857], [-99.12853299865812, 19.35559176853869], [-99.1284475830524, 19.355585806587758], [-99.12843758009667, 19.35572386394384], [-99.12843896672702, 19.35580036439833], [-99.1285217636758, 19.355803785783124], [-99.12874253394993, 19.355811161553483], [-99.12872812766815, 19.355858045825645], [-99.12844396034225, 19.355851686017527], [-99.12837265656651, 19.355780376021457]], [[-99.12839041140623, 19.35571127383799], [-99.12839041140623, 19.355591169786976], [-99.12812965365379, 19.35558438971694], [-99.12812965365379, 19.355704493772947], [-99.12839041140623, 19.35571127383799]]], [[[-99.12883493151176, 19.35561441573923], [-99.12883698472241, 19.355624101551697], [-99.12872611134738, 19.3556241015517], [-99.12872303153138, 19.355590201205565], [-99.1286860737397, 19.355595044112576], [-99.12866451502788, 19.355562112342], [-99.12867888750243, 19.355534992055336], [-99.12883493151176, 19.355535960637084], [-99.12883493151176, 19.35561441573923]]], [[[-99.12904846541927, 19.35562894445771], [-99.12904435899797, 19.355635724525893], [-99.1289581241507, 19.35563185020125], [-99.12892424617499, 19.355604729926192], [-99.12892732599096, 19.355541772127427], [-99.12904846541927, 19.355545646454217], [-99.12904846541927, 19.35562894445771]]], [[[-99.1289067938845, 19.35562894445771], [-99.1288657296715, 19.355628944457724], [-99.12886778288215, 19.35560763567016], [-99.12888420856733, 19.35560763567016], [-99.1289067938845, 19.35562894445771]]]]}",Ausencia,,,Instituciones académicas públicas,603.0,,,,,Cruz del Sur,1761,4,,DE E. IZTAPALAPA A PASEO CANAL NACIONAL,CAMELLON AV. CRUZ DEL SUR,Coyoacán,,,,,Equipamientos urbanos con vegetación,1187.69307083,,419.012097243,600,
6,"19.4042043692,-99.0889814062","{""type"": ""MultiPolygon"", ""coordinates"": [[[[-99.0887131101133, 19.402005345470446], [-99.08943329268284, 19.40209536829164], [-99.08972908195247, 19.402635505218782], [-99.08987054638578, 19.402931294488415], [-99.09000558061757, 19.40307918912324], [-99.09070004238104, 19.40326566496713], [-99.09108585447187, 19.403439280408005], [-99.09149095716722, 19.403490722020116], [-99.09107299406884, 19.403825092498828], [-99.09077720479921, 19.40434593882144], [-99.09073862359014, 19.40484106433799], [-99.09092509943403, 19.4054069220712], [-99.09107942427035, 19.405651269728725], [-99.0887066799118, 19.40547122408633], [-99.08633393555326, 19.40514971401065], [-99.08652041139715, 19.40417232338057], [-99.08666187583043, 19.40396012673062], [-99.08690622348796, 19.40382509249882], [-99.08729203557878, 19.403735069677637], [-99.08802507855134, 19.403696488468555], [-99.08821798459677, 19.403580744841303], [-99.08852020406789, 19.403252804564108], [-99.0886616685012, 19.40284127166723], [-99.0887131101133, 19.402005345470446]]]]}",Ausencia,,,Deportivos,601.0,,,,,63,276,8,,,CIUDAD DEPORTIVA MAGDALENA MIXIHUCA,Iztacalco,,,,,Equipamientos urbanos con vegetación,118007.516203,,1640.1324631,600,
7,"19.3190694734,-99.1342176003","{""type"": ""MultiPolygon"", ""coordinates"": [[[[-99.13445863166892, 19.319090234771572], [-99.1340115097695, 19.319066186201773], [-99.13401149431866, 19.319047229714673], [-99.13446014254731, 19.319078687058592], [-99.13445863166892, 19.319090234771572]]]]}",Ausencia,,,Camellones centrales y laterales,203.0,,,,,Calle 11,1204,4,,,,Coyoacán,,,,,Áreas verdes complementarias o ligadas a la red vial,79.6452348698,,97.6876386145,200,
8,"19.3957759227,-99.095959744","{""type"": ""MultiPolygon"", ""coordinates"": [[[[-99.09643673797211, 19.39643748611651], [-99.09534186582249, 19.396291503163233], [-99.09545135303745, 19.395145536979953], [-99.09659002007305, 19.395240425899587], [-99.09643673797211, 19.39643748611651]]]]}",Ausencia,,,Plazas,301.0,,,,,Te,147,8,,AV. RIO CHURUBUSCO ESQ. AV. TE.,PLAZA BENITO JUAREZ,Iztacalco,,,,,Plazas y jardines,15384.3009409,,496.86464831,300,
9,"19.3867957786,-99.1222546675","{""type"": ""MultiPolygon"", ""coordinates"": [[[[-99.12229064767064, 19.387401736376923], [-99.1221652867301, 19.387387544572327], [-99.12218420913624, 19.3865786117107], [-99.1222125927454, 19.386245104302844], [-99.12223624575304, 19.38622381659595], [-99.12233085778365, 19.38621435539289], [-99.1223545107913, 19.386249834904365], [-99.12231666597907, 19.387016192352224], [-99.12229064767064, 19.387401736376923]]]]}",Ausencia,,,Camellones centrales y laterales,203.0,,,,,Playa Icacos,57,8,,,CAMELLON EJE 2 OTE. (CALZ. DE LA VIGA),Iztacalco,,,,,Áreas verdes complementarias o ligadas a la red vial,1954.1947411,,285.512838578,200,
10,"19.3993682017,-99.0650339407","{""type"": ""MultiPolygon"", ""coordinates"": [[[[-99.0653578459828, 19.39953290860559], [-99.06473916417852, 19.39940321929267], [-99.06466687833198, 19.399354320043532], [-99.06467538254923, 19.39927778208837], [-99.06472428179835, 19.39924163916509], [-99.06477105499317, 19.399209748350433], [-99.0653961149604, 19.399352193989227], [-99.0653578459828, 19.39953290860559]]]]}",Ausencia,,,Instituciones académicas públicas,603.0,,,,,,246,8,,,,Iztacalco,,,,,Equipamientos urbanos con vegetación,1537.43367528,,184.809532193,600,
11,"19.4032885704,-99.1185855493","{""type"": ""MultiPolygon"", ""coordinates"": [[[[-99.11872453593787, 19.403379290447244], [-99.11865349448885, 19.403426252016555], [-99.1184524719233, 19.40320940042538], [-99.11851422989488, 19.403144851794167], [-99.11872453593787, 19.403379290447244]]]]}",Ausencia,,,Deportivos,601.0,,,,,Coyuya,370,8,,,,Iztacalco,,,,,Equipamientos urbanos con vegetación,307.288313697,,84.7605547234,600,
12,"19.4043545375,-99.0660468744","{""type"": ""MultiPolygon"", ""coordinates"": [[[[-99.0661954044627, 19.404439022222363], [-99.06592996050563, 19.404414039261702], [-99.06585188875354, 19.404276632978032], [-99.06620789594304, 19.404301615938703], [-99.0661954044627, 19.404439022222363]]]]}",Ausencia,,,Unidades habitacionales,602.0,,,,,PASILLO C,206,8,,,,Iztacalco,,,,,Equipamientos urbanos con vegetación,486.511092729,,98.0210070704,600,
13,"19.3768201956,-99.0387882652","{""type"": ""MultiPolygon"", ""coordinates"": [[[[-99.0389934443415, 19.37674016966787], [-99.03884002824203, 19.37699808622294], [-99.03881575848966, 19.37698604147009], [-99.03884197819207, 19.376939399922747], [-99.03877996490088, 19.376905188050586], [-99.03875336639393, 19.376951518422988], [-99.03863288666025, 19.376884332683353], [-99.03877615461283, 19.376621910849266], [-99.03882391059727, 19.37664556261936], [-99.03869974503816, 19.376857302127842], [-99.03884420689062, 19.3769271310543], [-99.0389612090521, 19.376721023007747], [-99.0389934443415, 19.37674016966787]]]]}",Ausencia,,,Instituciones académicas públicas,603.0,,,,,,1603,9,,,,Iztapalapa,,,,,Equipamientos urbanos con vegetación,359.395473151,,181.639291396,600,
14,"19.3551543685,-99.0634221055","{""type"": ""MultiPolygon"", ""coordinates"": [[[[-99.06378417273184, 19.355089491684396], [-99.06369821196013, 19.35538236157387], [-99.06317528393222, 19.355258455146853], [-99.0632540813063, 19.35496558503614], [-99.06378417273184, 19.355089491684396]], [[-99.06342719674923, 19.355304638462396], [-99.06350002462531, 19.355037676189166], [-99.06332929698144, 19.355003883465073], [-99.06332929698145, 19.35500388346508], [-99.06326721420197, 19.35526971937136], [-99.06342719674923, 19.355304638462396]], [[-99.06376865203693, 19.35510526161609], [-99.06358479149775, 19.355064710363898], [-99.06350957582171, 19.355329419749133], [-99.06368746686366, 19.355373350200534], [-99.06376865203693, 19.35510526161609]]]]}",Ausencia,,,Unidades habitacionales,602.0,,,,,Universidad,1621,9,,,,Iztapalapa,,,,,Equipamientos urbanos con vegetación,773.389620598,,377.561831176,600,
15,"19.3770235576,-99.0693724976","{""type"": ""MultiPolygon"", ""coordinates"": [[[[-99.06984193981164, 19.376498965087933], [-99.06967341471146, 19.37740477277865], [-99.06965902920152, 19.377436569661793], [-99.0696233513866, 19.377436583316296], [-99.06890482491414, 19.377320102842926], [-99.06888021414373, 19.37730726922305], [-99.06887282370059, 19.377286256304412], [-99.06888264376452, 19.37723371329709], [-99.06892560100813, 19.37699084875212], [-99.06906435047583, 19.37634864922371], [-99.06919476606338, 19.37636728031873], [-99.0691911878667, 19.376406500024675], [-99.06984193981164, 19.376498965087933]], [[-99.06964053918936, 19.377351930107146], [-99.06965157563349, 19.377267279250304], [-99.06960051801522, 19.377263796167224], [-99.0695907137969, 19.377353116708868], [-99.06964053918936, 19.377351930107146]], [[-99.06953659014127, 19.377372401805783], [-99.06955008593845, 19.377284831165877], [-99.0694897988291, 19.37727551388032], [-99.06949592194961, 19.377208961774816], [-99.06951314569847, 19.377208955195993], [-99.06967186016823, 19.377232245291758], [-99.06968413057893, 19.37715635050778], [-99.06942452981875, 19.377122591082475], [-99.06939875106605, 19.377256867990738], [-99.06928555800597, 19.377237062949096], [-99.0692696020274, 19.377325802046528], [-99.06953659014127, 19.377372401805783]], [[-99.06938397845659, 19.377234690368415], [-99.06940607581181, 19.37712259812214], [-99.06918103017782, 19.377084140004982], [-99.06908604272513, 19.37707200229364], [-99.06908372810484, 19.377080689353672], [-99.06893977559014, 19.377053890532434], [-99.06891400234211, 19.37720217784948], [-99.06902596555784, 19.377223151128813], [-99.069032100668, 19.377184619988483], [-99.06938397845659, 19.377234690368415]], [[-99.06967735815165, 19.37714234262376], [-99.06971048994826, 19.376941513089477], [-99.06959914395503, 19.376925210153562], [-99.06959607746337, 19.376946810812907], [-99.06949519294426, 19.376940427900394], [-99.0694681993528, 19.377110899018476], [-99.06967735815165, 19.37714234262376]], [[-99.06958992315975, 19.37693980792772], [-99.06960588041555, 19.376854571418], [-99.06966200660409, 19.37685967794138], [-99.06966705795462, 19.376871553069574], [-99.06972707047022, 19.376875540737526], [-99.06979150626093, 19.376515913765587], [-99.06952390409329, 19.376468730837036], [-99.06949999121758, 19.376650876189824], [-99.0693769581866, 19.376635161350013], [-99.06940886666436, 19.376450094113476], [-99.06918309730779, 19.37641165127114], [-99.06918615817611, 19.37637662391078], [-99.0690741974872, 19.376360320885166], [-99.06893300323065, 19.377039882620345], [-99.06917353561163, 19.377075985077084], [-99.06917966575324, 19.377025778535092], [-99.06912971952386, 19.3770181327634], [-99.06916340849132, 19.37679130149271], [-99.06934627693818, 19.376813222870727], [-99.06933154882886, 19.376896123810482], [-99.06920728610366, 19.376882160635077], [-99.06918090957312, 19.37705788540686], [-99.06942390281513, 19.37709457036668], [-99.06946073016283, 19.37690424732442], [-99.06950809786004, 19.376910066936286], [-99.06950933778177, 19.376932833489047], [-99.06958992315975, 19.37693980792772]]]]}",Ausencia,,,Asistencia Social con vegetación CDMX,605.0,,,,,Guerra de Reforma,1220,9,,,,Iztapalapa,,,,,Equipamientos urbanos con vegetación,2796.43973024,,1229.61407429,600,
16,"19.3100477712,-99.1229215101","{""type"": ""MultiPolygon"", ""coordinates"": [[[[-99.12323174860985, 19.310039199674186], [-99.12267233782443, 19.310297361562764], [-99.12272157089691, 19.310091470955605], [-99.12275102399722, 19.310010903671852], [-99.12287173176779, 19.30985915402128], [-99.12288773251632, 19.309860896399506], [-99.12291111822572, 19.309862638777734], [-99.12293019604128, 19.309861477192264], [-99.12295173551047, 19.309851022922597], [-99.12296681313892, 19.30984303702172], [-99.12298712178136, 19.30983359913841], [-99.12323174860985, 19.310039199674186]]]]}",Ausencia,,,Plazas,301.0,,,,,,1119,4,,AV. CANAL DE MIRAMONTES Y LAS BOMBAS,ALAMEDA SUR,Coyoacán,,,,,Plazas y jardines,1432.70288521,,166.400282986,300,
17,"19.4694230906,-99.1545109192","{""type"": ""MultiPolygon"", ""coordinates"": [[[[-99.15495864542359, 19.469721288229064], [-99.15402876353782, 19.469249350910843], [-99.15404278228738, 19.4691760516818], [-99.15405547697094, 19.469120872018284], [-99.15471695245739, 19.469456698034477], [-99.1549942633344, 19.46959789760947], [-99.15496882196955, 19.469720016160814], [-99.15495864542359, 19.469721288229064]]]]}",Ausencia,,,Parques,401.0,,,,,Ciprés,682,2,,,,Azcapotzalco,,,,,"Parques, arboledas y alamedas",1547.7341124,,251.806015391,400,
18,"19.3096994745,-99.1224381173","{""type"": ""MultiPolygon"", ""coordinates"": [[[[-99.12281603685469, 19.309827646011666], [-99.1226769534251, 19.310051831902076], [-99.12196922800905, 19.309855524066585], [-99.12250709932519, 19.309141147409743], [-99.12250492782337, 19.30918956536046], [-99.12250833015207, 19.30926311437699], [-99.12256987149289, 19.309447807040033], [-99.12271880153672, 19.309637145841855], [-99.12281603685472, 19.309706841052105], [-99.12279634362574, 19.30975562768113], [-99.12281603685469, 19.309827646011666]]]]}",Ausencia,,,Plazas,301.0,,,,,,1127,4,,AV. CANAL DE MIRAMONTES Y LAS BOMBAS,ALAMEDA SUR,Coyoacán,,,,,Plazas y jardines,4277.71858956,,291.318369857,300,
19,,,Ausencia,,,Instituciones académicas públicas,603.0,,,,,Elisa Acuña Rosete,1637,9,,,,Iztapalapa,,,,,Equipamientos urbanos con vegetación,,,,600,
20,"19.311307363,-99.11899654","{""type"": ""MultiPolygon"", ""coordinates"": [[[[-99.1186083126073, 19.311237717878324], [-99.11862406707364, 19.31117595824034], [-99.11929181404919, 19.311366955565592], [-99.1193124160424, 19.311299477493332], [-99.11936695073224, 19.311313201849142], [-99.11932938239035, 19.311433289912195], [-99.1186083126073, 19.311237717878324]]]]}",Ausencia,,,Asistencia Social con vegetación CDMX,605.0,,,,,NINGUNO,1789,4,,,,Coyoacán,,,,,Equipamientos urbanos con vegetación,556.219134182,,186.637938939,600,
21,"19.310098846,-99.1196174102","{""type"": ""MultiPolygon"", ""coordinates"": [[[[-99.12011589380059, 19.309849264078842], [-99.11994259467671, 19.310421116330296], [-99.11990381445314, 19.31041196671007], [-99.11989048375132, 19.310454283699926], [-99.11930150910497, 19.31031818307268], [-99.11943118047793, 19.30978521650218], [-99.11904337824133, 19.30968457025967], [-99.1190676158811, 19.309602223287808], [-99.11956448749638, 19.30970286958112], [-99.11949783398724, 19.309956772454594], [-99.11999106995594, 19.310082580038994], [-99.12006499475751, 19.309832108480695], [-99.12011589380059, 19.309849264078842]]]]}",Ausencia,,,Asistencia Social con vegetación CDMX,605.0,,,,,NINGUNO,1787,4,,,,Coyoacán,,,,,Equipamientos urbanos con vegetación,3892.08984332,,421.268903238,600,
22,"19.4683399426,-99.1533865751","{""type"": ""MultiPolygon"", ""coordinates"": [[[[-99.15382943268317, 19.468442736804967], [-99.1532898565414, 19.468381303418376], [-99.15276573143096, 19.468330893487657], [-99.15273360622442, 19.468294008991563], [-99.15274193498158, 19.46824046698125], [-99.15277643983269, 19.46821429088731], [-99.15307032597939, 19.46824284662408], [-99.15343913491806, 19.468295453302705], [-99.15383657163731, 19.46834041206715], [-99.15404954985566, 19.468360639048825], [-99.15406501754784, 19.468384435497875], [-99.15407215648212, 19.468427269106108], [-99.15405430914564, 19.468466533246925], [-99.15382943268317, 19.468442736804967]]]]}",Ausencia,,,Camellones centrales y laterales,203.0,,,,,Ciclopista,705,2,,,CAMELLON ANTNIO VALERIANO,Azcapotzalco,,,,,Áreas verdes complementarias o ligadas a la red vial,1661.00305153,,299.237259586,200,
23,"19.4683830071,-99.1525248671","{""type"": ""MultiPolygon"", ""coordinates"": [[[[-99.15262057309153, 19.468455824844984], [-99.15250278066881, 19.46840228283467], [-99.1524171134523, 19.4683523102917], [-99.1523754696665, 19.468318995263058], [-99.15239093735838, 19.46830590721608], [-99.15242782185436, 19.468321374907955], [-99.15245756741565, 19.468342791712082], [-99.15247422492997, 19.46834517135699], [-99.15251348907088, 19.468348740824347], [-99.15255513285669, 19.468353500114148], [-99.15258130895062, 19.468367777983566], [-99.15261700362417, 19.46841061159183], [-99.1526431797181, 19.468440357153117], [-99.15264555936301, 19.46845820448989], [-99.15262057309153, 19.468455824844984]]]]}",Ausencia,,,"Veg. Arbórea, arbustiva y herbácea de glorietas",201.0,,,,,Antonio Valeriano,707,2,,,,Azcapotzalco,,,,,Áreas verdes complementarias o ligadas a la red vial,144.761064338,,68.7434558837,200,
...
```

Comment: a very broken one, parts of it are csv encoded JSON which is horrible to contemplate.

Comment: It is not broken at all for GDAL. Probably GDAL has created it, too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is probably written with GDAL https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/csv.html

> Otherwise, if one or several columns contain a geometry definition
> encoded as WKT, WKB (encoded in hexadecimal) or GeoJSON (in which case
> the GeoJSON content must be formatted to follow CSV rules, that is to
> say it must be surrounded by double-quotes, and double-quotes inside
> the string must be repeated for proper escaping), the name of such
> column(s) can be derived from the GEOM_POSSIBLE_NAMES open option.

The data can be read with GDAL by telling that the geometry should be searched from the "geo_shape" column.

```
ogrinfo json.csv -al -oo geom_possible_names=geo_shape
INFO: Open of `json.csv'
      using driver `CSV' successful.

Layer name: json
Geometry: Unknown (any)
Feature Count: 8
Extent: (-99.206581, 19.319047) - (-99.086334, 19.488192)
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
Geometry Column = geo_shape
id: String (0.0)
geo_point_2d: String (0.0)
geo_shape: String (0.0)
muerdago: String (0.0)
p_sp_her_d: String (0.0)
zonifica: String (0.0)
subcat_sed: String (0.0)
subcve_sed: String (0.0)
p_manejo: String (0.0)
tipo: String (0.0)
p_sp_abs_d: String (0.0)
f_decreto: String (0.0)
direccion: String (0.0)
gid: String (0.0)
cve_delg: String (0.0)
p_arbustiv: String (0.0)
ubicacion: String (0.0)
nombre: String (0.0)
delegacion: String (0.0)
p_sp_arb_d: String (0.0)
p_herbaceo: String (0.0)
p_sp_do_mu: String (0.0)
p_arboreo: String (0.0)
categoria: String (0.0)
superficie: String (0.0)
e_urbano: String (0.0)
perimetro: String (0.0)
cve_sedema: String (0.0)
responsabl: String (0.0)
OGRFeature(json):1
  id (String) = 0
  geo_point_2d (String) = 19.4877568178,-99.2060645931
  geo_shape (String) = {"type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[-99.2063901369562, 19.488192302215793], [-99.20556202053083, 19.487955527548596], [-99.20572621602916, 19.487317782714538], [-99.20633421530209, 19.487497445904744], [-99.20658050854802, 19.48756645560521], [-99.20646632656124, 19.48794381572397], [-99.2063901369562, 19.488192302215793]]]]}
  muerdago (String) = Ausencia
  p_sp_her_d (String) =
  zonifica (String) =
  subcat_sed (String) = Panteones
  subcve_sed (String) = 604.0
  p_manejo (String) =
  tipo (String) =
  p_sp_abs_d (String) =
  f_decreto (String) =
  direccion (String) = Romßn ┴lvarez Moreno
  gid (String) = 268
  cve_delg (String) = 2
  p_arbustiv (String) =
  ubicacion (String) =
  nombre (String) =
  delegacion (String) = Azcapotzalco
  p_sp_arb_d (String) =
  p_herbaceo (String) =
  p_sp_do_mu (String) =
  p_arboreo (String) =
  categoria (String) = Equipamientos urbanos con vegetaci¾n
  superficie (String) = 6660.02755418
  e_urbano (String) =
  perimetro (String) = 329.26473795
  cve_sedema (String) = 600
  responsabl (String) =
  MULTIPOLYGON (((-99.2063901369562 19.4881923022158,-99.2055620205308 19.4879555275486,-99.2057262160292 19.4873177827145,-99.2063342153021 19.4874974459047,-99.206580508548 19.4875664556052,-99.2064663265612 19.487943815724,-99.2063901369562 19.4881923022158)))
...
```

Conversion into shapefile succeeds with ogr2ogr

```
ogr2ogr json.shp json.csv -oo geom_possible_names=geo_shape -oo KEEP_GEOM_COLUMNS=NO
```

With QGIS open the csv file with "Add vector layer" and define the geometry field in here

[image]